# how to start mysql2 server?

Tags: mysql, mysql2

I am trying to get some open source code running on my local machine.  It uses mysql2, and I have not used this database before.  I had some errors I was able to fix by running:

```
sudo apt-get install libmysql-ruby libmysqlclient-dev
```

I start up the rails server but when I go to http://localhost:3000/, I get the following error:

```
Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)
```

Do I need to start the MySQL server?  How would I do that?

Comment: Try running `$ mysqld` to start mysql. You will also have to create and migrate the database with `$ rake db:create && rake db:migrate`

Answer (score 4):

If you have your gem installed, start mysql before you run `$ rails server`

```
$ mysql.server start
```

Answer (score 1):

**To install MySql database:**

```
sudo apt-get install mysql-server
```

**To start MySql server:**

```
/etc/init.d/mysql start
```

**To stop MySql server:**

```
/etc/init.d/mysql stop
```

**To restart MySql server:**

```
/etc/init.d/mysql restart
```

**To check the status of  MySql server:**

```
/etc/init.d/mysql status
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no **mysql2** server. **mysql2** is the name of a MySQL client gem (Ruby library). All you need is to install and start MySQL server.

It seems your server is Debian or Ubuntu. Execute `apt-get install mysql-server` to install MySQL. Your MySQL server will automatically start (by Upstart on Ubuntu or sysinit on Debian).

Answer (score 0):

Just type command on terminal

/opt/lampp/lampp start if you have lamp server.Please let me know is it working for you,either I'll do other thing.

Comment: Why do you assume John is using LAMPP?

Comment: as per my understanding he is using mysql adapter and that error come when you used mysql addapter and server is not started. So I assumed he has LAMP .Also I thing if he has not ,He can install LAMPP and use other features like PHPMyAdmin. I just want to help him :(